# Quiero formar esta oracion en una sola linea, SIN que se vaya para abajo

Tags: php, html, css

Tengo un inconveniente, yo debería hacer lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, parte del texto se va para abajo y me queda de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que quede todo junto como en la primer imagen, el verdadero inconveniente es que es un echo php:

```
  echo "Examen". "<p class='ex'> <b>en " . $days ." dias, " .$hours . " horas y ".$min. " minutos.</b></p>";
```

Alguno tiene idea que se puede hacer o que es lo que hace que se vea asi?

PD: Solo paso esta parte del código por considerarla la estrictamente necesaria, de otra forma el código seria muy largo y no tiene caso entrar en detalles.

¡Gracias a todos por su atención!

Comment: En lugar de `<p>` intenta con `<span>`.

Comment: ¡Gracias! ¡Eso resolvio mi duda!

Comment: [`<p>` es una etiqueta de párrafo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) [`<span>` es una etiqueta que agrupa dentro de una línea](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)

Comment: Otro apunte: en PHP es muy útil trabajar con comillas dobles cuando vas a encadenar variables en el contenido. Eso evita tantas concatenaciones con `.` que hace el código más verboso. Cuando dentro del contenido hay comillas dobles, las puedes escapar con \. Por ejemplo, esto es más limpio: `echo "<p>Examen <span class=\"ex\"><b>en $days dias, $hours horas y $min minutos.</b></span></p>";`

Comment: Otra alternativa interesante es `printf`, que te evita declarar variables innecesariamente, suponiendo que estuvieras trabajando aquí con un objeto `DateInterval` u otro con propiedades a las que accedes a los días, horas, minutos o lo que sea, podrías hacer esto: `printf('<p>Examen <span class="ex"><b>en %d dias, %d horas y %d minutos.</b></span></p>',$di->d,$di->h,$di->s);` Aquí `$di` es un objeto, y tomas los datos de ahí sin necesidad de declarar `$days, $hours, $min`. Aquí no se escapan las comillas dobles, porque se usan comillas simples por fuera y marcadores para los valores.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias por las alternativas, son muy utiles!

Comment: @aloMalbarez Gracias por la aclaración!